# JPA collection saving id, but not other fields

Tags: mysql, angularjs, hibernate, jpa, jhipster

So, I have a `JHipster` generated application with a number of entities and collections, amongst the main entities I have the Study, which has a number of collections.

One of them is the StudySites, it is a `ManyToMany` where the owner is Study:

The relation and setter in Study:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "study_sites_study",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="studys_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="study_sitess_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<StudySites> studySites = new HashSet<>();

public void setStudySites(Set<StudySites> studySites) {
        studySites.stream().forEach(ss-> {
            Set<Study> setStudys=ss.getStudys();
            setStudys.add(this);
            ss.setStudys(setStudys);
        });
        this.studySites = studySites;
    }
```

The relation in StudySites:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studySites")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Study> studys = new HashSet<>();
```

The relations and the way we handle it all can be pretty complicated to explain and it would result in quite a big post, so I will try to bottomline it saying that we bundle all the information in a `DTO` with `Angular` and send it to the backend, where it decompresses the Studys and puts all collections in a StudyDTO, all of that works just fine, I have all data in all fields right up until we call the save method from the repository, where it saves every other collection just fine except for the fields of this particular entity.

If I add a StudySite to the Study, `Hibernate` will assign an id to it, save it and also save the relation in the join table, so when I load the Study again it will show the StudySite but with empty fields.

This happens when I insert a new one or if I try to update an existing one

I have also logged the variable binding from Hibernate where you can appreciate all values going in as null, yet when saving in the join table it has retrieved the assigned id and the study_id:

```
Hibernate: /* insert org.wwarn.nmfisurveyor.datamanagement.domain.StudySites */ insert into study_sites (country_id, dms_lat, dms_lon, google_lat, google_lon, province_name, site_name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2017-02-14 17:12:50.972 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.972 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.972 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.973 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.973 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.973 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.973 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
Hibernate: /* insert collection row org.wwarn.nmfisurveyor.datamanagement.domain.Study.studySites */ insert into study_sites_study (studys_id, study_sitess_id) values (?, ?)
2017-02-14 17:12:50.980 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4089]
2017-02-14 17:12:50.980 TRACE 8859 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1629]
```

Any suggestions welcome

PS: Amongst the various things I've done to track down the error, I completely erased the entity and all references to it (liquibase, everything) And recreated with a different name, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this, at first I just changed the `cascadeType` to `ALL` instead of `PERSIST`, it worked ok all the time it didn't need to merge the same instance of a `StudySite` to different studies in a same form.  So after some thinking I realised the underlying issue was that in a `Many to Many` relation you can't expect `Hibernate` to save a newly created entity and also save the relation in the join table, at least not the way we were doing it.

So I just tweaked the design, opening a modal when the user needs to create a new Entity, saving it first and then saving it in the join table when the user hits save for the whole form

What was happening before was that `Hibernate` couldn't persist the new fields, but was saving the relation in the join table, hence the generated id with empty fields

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the culprit but in my opinion your setter method:

```
public void setStudySites(Set<StudySites> studySites) {
        studySites.stream().forEach(ss-> {
            Set<Study> setStudys=ss.getStudys();
            setStudys.add(this);
            ss.setStudys(setStudys);
        });
        this.studySites = studySites;
    }
```

Should be cut down to:

```
public void setStudySites(Set<StudySites> studySites) {
        this.studySites = studySites;
    }
```

The traversal of the collection and setting the Studys entity, I would leave for some Repository / Service method to handle.

Comment: Tried that just for in case earlier on, but that creates an error when saving as you are not adding studies to the collection of studies when setting them in the StudyDTO.  However, all other ManyToMany collections have the same setter.